# If upgrading Composer from 1.7 to 1.9 will it affect the laravel 5.0 project

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

If upgrading Composer from 1.7 to 1.9 will it affect the laravel 5.0 project

on Cpanel there are larvavel 5.0 projects.  if i upgrade composer from 1.7 to 1.9 to install the latest version of laravel project will the comopser affect the laravel projects on cpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the changelog and it doesn't seem like there are breaking changes that should cause issues. I would go ahead and update. https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md